# Change certain letter to Capital?

Tags: c#

I am taking in user Input in c# I know how to change to upper and lower case. How do I can a certain letter? eg User Input "James"and i display "JaMes"?

This is what I've done so far:

```
namespace Strings
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Insert 3 letter name containing 'A'");
            string Userinput = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static string UppercaseFirst(string s)
        {
            // Check for empty string.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please insert a name");
            }

            // Return char and concat substring.
            return char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what problem are you having?

Comment: You have an index of this _certain_ characters; for example `2` in your case? Please clarify your question, it is not clear at all.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me

Answer (score 0):

So you want to make every `m` uppercase? The easiest way is to use `String.Replace`:

```
string result = s.Replace("m", "M");
```

Another way:

```
string result = string.Concat(s.Select(c => c == 'm' ? 'M' : c));
```

Another more efficient way (if the string is large) that also supports multiple characters:

```
char[] toUpper = {'m'};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    char c = s[i];
    sb.Append(toUpper.Contains(c) ? Char.ToUpper(c) : c);
}
result = sb.ToString();
```

The collection can also be used in the other approaches(`string.Replace` in a loop).

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this? It is not 100% clear from the question what OP wants to do, so this may very well be the answer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight quite common behavior in SO. Unfortunately, some downvote without any reasoning.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - conversely, it's not 100% clear from the question what the OP wants, so why would you even answer it or upvote it?  Hooray for wild guesses!

Answer (score 0):

According to text of your question

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Insert 3 letter name containing 'A'");

  string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

  string yourCharacter = "m";

  userInput = UpperCharacter(userInput, yourCharacter);
}

private static string UpperCharacter(string srcString, string characterToReplace)
{
  // Check for empty string.
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(srcString))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Please insert a name");
  }
  // Return char and concat substring.
  return srcString.Replace(characterToReplace, characterToReplace.ToUpper());
}
```